# Coupled function optimization

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

I am looking for guidance on how to perform the following optimization.

Let's say I have the below 3 functions:

$f_1(A, S)$

$f_2(R, A, S)$

$f_3(R, S, X, f_1)$

I would like to minimize function 3 with respect to R, S and X, as in the following:

$eq_1 \min_{R,S, X}f_3(R, S, X, f_1)$

And minimize function 2, with respect to A and S conditional on the R in equation 1. This minimum fully parametrize function 1, which is used in function 3.

$eq_2 \min_{A, S}f_2(R, A, S)$

An example of such a system: Let's say I have a regression model of my environment ($f_3$), and a controlling model of some widget ($f_1$) in that environment, from the learned environment model, I would like to parameterize optimal control A and S dependent on the parameters of $f_3$, R.

I have been toying with a couple approaches this problem:

1: iteratively optimize a step in equation 1, then step in equation 2, then 1, etc until convergence. However, the shared variable S, makes this more challenging. And I am not sure what convergence guarantees I have.

2: Another approach is to sum equation 1 and 2, and minimize all of these variables at once, however, it seems if I sum these two and solve as one simultaneous equation, there will be issues with parameter R: R should not be optimized in equation 2 but should be in equation 1. I have initially been using a quasi-newton method (LBFGS) to solve the summed system of equations, however, we can see that the derivative of the separated equations doesn't equal the minimizing direction of the summed equations because R is a parameter of equation 2. Therefore, the quasi-newton hessian starts to adjust to the minimizing direction of the summed equation by change R such equation 2 is reduced by changes in R. I believe if I use a first order optimizer I will not have these issues because the optimizer is not dependent on the summed equation output (only the partial derivative), however, first order methods tend to either be slower, or have many manually tuned variables.

One thought has been maybe I can enforce the the hessian matrix to be blocked such that the the second order method has the correct update direction by ignoring changes in R in the second equation, but not sure if this is possible.

Any guidance, papers, books etc would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you will benefit by reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilevel_optimization

Comment: Thank you Mark. I had been searching for something like this!